# Por que razão dizemos «dois em um» e não «dois num»?

Tags: gramática, expressões-idiomáticas, pronomes, contrações

Em Portugal diz-se e escreve-se ***num*** e ***numa***, e não ***em um*** ou ***em uma***, mesmo nos registos mais formais. Mas há pelo menos uma exceção: a expressão ***dois em um***, como por exemplo:

> Estive ***numa*** loja e comprei este produto que lava e amacia: são ***dois em um.***

No Brasil poderá não ser tão óbvio, para quem está a ver as coisas aqui de Portugal, se *dois em um* é excecional, dada a tendência para empregar *em um/uma* em vez de *num/numa* nos registos formais. Mas numa busca rápida encontrei ***dois em um*** neste [artigo](http://mmrecords.com.br/dois-em-um/) e nesta [canção](http://www.vagalume.com.br/gatinha-manhosa/dois-em-um.html) que também usam *num* e *numa*, e a letra da canção é até bem informal. Confirma-se portanto que *dois em um* é excecional também no Brasil? Ou num registo informal ficaria na frase acima ***numa loja (...) são dois num***?

A pergunta é então o porquê de ***dois em um***? É apenas por uma questão de sonoridade: ***são dois em um!*** soa bem, e ***são dois num!*** soaria muito brusco? Ou há alguma subtileza gramatical que nos leve a dizer ***são dois em um!*** mas ***figos? Estão ali dois num prato***.

Procurei outros casos em que empregasse ***em um***, e consegui encontrar apenas uma frase arrevesada. Imaginem-me ao telefone:

> A mesa é muito pesada para a levares sozinha lá para fora. Espera pelos convidados. ***Em um*** deles chegando, pede-lhe que te ajude.

Seria gramatical dizer-se ***num deles chegando***? Este ***um*** é gramaticalmente o mesmo que o de ***dois em um***? Ou por que razão ***em um deles chegando*** soa melhor (se é que concordam comigo) que ***num deles chegando***?

Comment: Bem, vejo que o "p" de excepcional caiu em pt-PT e isso significa que não era pronunciado.  Aqui continua sendo pronunciado.  Já em "subtileza" me parece estranho que o "b" seja pronunciado em pt-PT.  Alguma explicação?

Comment: @Centaurus o ***b*** de *subtil* é pronunciado em Portugal. Encontro-o em autores brasileiros do séc. XIX. Imagino que no Brasil fosse mudo e tenha caído com a reforma de 1943. Mas Fernão Lopes, um dos maiores escritores do sec. XV, antes do português chegar ao Brasil, escrevia *sotil*. Muitas destas consoantes foram latinismos adotados por escritores renascentistas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consultando a lista de ocorrências de `"em" [lema="um"]` no CETEMPúblico, salta à vista que, na maioria das ocorrências, *um* tem **função de quantificador numeral**. Por exemplo, `"em" "um" "milhão"` ocorre 47 vezes, contra apenas 8 de `"num" "milhão"`.

Por vezes, a escolha entre *em um* e *num* pode ter influência no significado:

> **Em um** mês, o preço do crude subiu 20%.

Com *num* poderíamos interpretar a frase como *num certo mês, ...*

Estando esta análise correta, seria já por isso de esperar uma preferência por *dois em um*, dado que o constraste numérico reforça o valor de cardinalidade. Por outro lado, se atenuarmos a leitura de cardinalidade, já podemos usar a contração: *vou converter dois objetos em um* vs. *vou converter dois objetos num único (objeto)*. Também poderá estar em jogo um carácter fixo da expressão *X em um*.

Recuando um pouco, é preciso dizer que a escolha entre as duas formas é largamente arbitrária. No Brasil, *em um* é longe preferido à contração na escrita (analogamente, raramente se usa *dum* na escrita em Portugal). E eu lembro-me de ter um professor de geografia que nunca usava a contração (não me lembro de onde era), por isso é possível que também haja alguma variação regional. Mesmo no CETEMPúblico, encontram-se algumas (raras) passagens onde estamos perante um artigo indefinido (há casos ainda mais óbvios, com *uns*/*umas*, mas esta é mais interessante):

> *par=ext2545-nd-91b-1*: Esperava que me escrevesses de todos os lugares por onde passasses; que as tuas cartas seriam mui extensas; que alimentarias a minha paixão com as esperanças de ainda ver-te; que uma inteira confiança na tua fidelidade me daria alguma espécie de repouso, e que ficaria assim **em um** estado assaz suportável, sem extrema dor.

Outro caso em que tipicamente não se faz a contração é quando o segundo elemento faz parte de um sujeito de uma oração infinitiva (independentemente de qual é a segunda partícula):

> *par=ext204613-clt-92b-1*: A novidade introduzida por Ice-T está **em ele** ser o primeiro artista negro procedente do rap a operar a transição para o heavy metal.

Quanto a *em + <gerúndio>*, creio que é análogo a este caso. Mas essa construção  (exprimindo tempo ou contingência) é arcaizante em Portugal; no Brasil a fobia de usar a contração complica a análise. Em todo o caso, procurei por `"nele" [temcagr="GER"]` no [*Corpus Brasileiro do Projeto AC/DC*](http://www.linguateca.pt/acesso/corpus.php?corpus=CBRAS) e nenhum dos resultados incluía a construção. Com `"em" "ele"`, temos esta passagem:

> Porém, reforçamos o fato de **em ele tendo** casa, e pessoas que de alguma forma o queriam e com os encaminhamentos já dados, ele estaria a desperdiçar e também de alguma forma tirar o lugar em instituições, de outros meninos que não possuíam suas condições.

Um exemplo em que a contração *em* + *o* → *no* não é feita:

> O que a reforma precisa é de criar as condições necessárias para que, **em o** País voltando a crescer, se ampliem também as ofertas de trabalho.

Comment: Também me parece que ser o *ele, um, etc.* parte do sujeito obsta a contração. Não sei é se isso é tendência ou se a gramática normativa diz algo acerca disso. No meu exemplo eu não diria *num deles chegando*; não sei se não  era capaz de dizer *a novidade está nele ser*.

Comment: @Jacinto É uma regra, sim, vê por exemplo [aqui](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/preposicao-seguida-de-artigo-definido-sem-contracao/32586). Com a preposição _de_, contudo, tende mais a não ser observada. Vê também [este artigo](http://sualingua.com.br/2016/02/28/antes-do-sol-nascer/).

Comment: Ahh, mas o segundo artigo diz que a contração de *de* com artigo ou pronome tem pergaminhos mesmo quando o artigo ou pronome fazem parte do sujeito. Mas a justificação, sendo fonética, parece-me não se aplicar ao *em*.

Comment: @Jacinto Sim, não me parece que a lógica seja completamente transponível para _em_, lógica essa, de resto, já de si bastante discutível. Muita gente diz _eu acabei **do** ver_ (_di-u_ também possível), mas nunca ninguém se lembraria de escrever dessa forma. A fonética não é completamente determinante. O que ele tem do seu lado são os tais pergaminhos.

Answer (score 2):

Acho que é que:

"num/numa" são contrações de "em" com o artigo indefinido "um/uma". O "um" em *"dois em um"* é um objeto definido, um número específico, não é um artigo.

Comment: Fiz umas correçõezitas na tua resposta. Mas eu não tenha a certeza que a tua resposta esteja correta, por isso não votei. Nós dizemos coisas como «achas que precisamos de dois caixotes, ou caberá tudo num?». O *um* deste *num* também não é um número específico?

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda. «achas que precisamos de dois caixotes, ou caberá tudo num?» pode ser artigo o número, me pareces. em inglês tem dois variantes de artigo indefinitivo como "um/uma": "one" e "a/an". Ambos são iguais como artigo, ainda "one" tem um aspeito numérico. em [priberam](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/num), "num" só tem o significado que eu descrevi.  embora não é um recurso definitivo.

Comment: Mas o [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/num) já indica também *num* = *em um* com *um* numeral.