# O termo "num/numa" está correto?

Tags: gramática, uso-de-palavras

Sempre ouço pessoas falando coisas como:

> Eu estou numa boa.
>
> Vamos num show?

É correto esse uso? Ou simplesmente seria uma abreviação?

Comment: Em Portugal só se diz, e escreve, *num* e *numa*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sim, perfeitamente gramatical. **"num" e "numa" são contrações da preposição "em" com o artigo indefinido um/uma.**    O que não está correto é **"Vamos num show"**.   Nós **vamos "a" ou "para"**  algum lugar, mas **não vamos "em" um lugar**. Nós "vamos **ao** cinema" mas "não vamos **no** cinema".  "Vamos **a** um show", mas não "vamos **num** show". Vamos **à** casa de nossos primos, mas não vamos **na** casa de nossos primos.

Referências:

1. http://www.dicio.com.br/numa/
2. http://www.dicio.com.br/num/
3. http://eumarkeller.blogspot.com.br/2011/03/ir-algum-lugar-ou-ir-para-algum-lugar.html

Answer (score 4):

A gramaticalidade de ***num*** e ***numa*** pode ser confirmada em qualquer dicionário. Por exemplo no [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/num) (com abreviaturas desabreviadas):

> **1.** Contração da preposição *em* com o artigo indefinido *um: Vive **num** sítio no interior*
>
> **2.** Contração da preposição *em* com o numeral *um: **Num** dos dedos havia a marca do anel*

Imagino que a tua dúvida venha da oposição de alguns ao uso de *num* e *numa* na linguagem cuidada. Para quem está em Portugal, como eu, essa oposição é surpreendente, pois *em um* e *em uma* praticamente desapareceram quer da língua falada quer da escrita, exceto nalgumas construções especiais, discutidas [nesta pergunta sobre *dois em um*](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3041/por-que-raz%C3%A3o-dizemos-dois-em-um-e-n%C3%A3o-dois-num). Mas mesmo olhando-se para a literatura brasileira, vê-se que *num* e *numa* têm sido amplamente usados, mesmo em textos académicos e linguagem cuidada. Eis alguns exemplos (ênfase minha):

> Em *Onde andará Dulce Veiga?*, nos deparamos com um narrador sem nome que se lança à procura de Dulce Veiga, cantora que fez relativo sucesso **numa época** anterior ao momento em que o narrador conta sua história e que desaparecera misteriosamente. [[Carlos André Ferreira, “Narrar ou não narrar. Caio Fernando Abreu: o sujeito e o não-dito do discurso da AIDS em *Onde andará Dulce Veiga?* em *Via Litterae*, v. 3, n. 1, p. 125-134. jan./jun. 2011]](http://www2.unucseh.ueg.br/vialitterae/assets/files/volume_revista/vol_3_num_1/Vol_3_1_Via_Litterae_8-63-CARLOS_ANDRE_FERREIRA.pdf)
>
> **Numa das esquinas** em frente ao parque, no meio da ventania, embaixo da quaresmeira coberta de flores roxas, estava Dulce Veiga. Toda vestida de vermelho, uma rosa branca aberta, presa na gola do casaco, a bolsa da mesma cor pendurada **num dos braços** cruzados, com luvas de cano curto brancas. [[Caio Fernando Abreu, *Onde Andará Dulce Veiga*, 1990]](https://books.google.pt/books?id=muvUBQAAQBAJ&pg=PT31&lpg=PT31&dq=bolsa%20da%20mesma%20cor%20pendurada%20num%20dos%20bra%C3%A7os%20cruzados&source=bl&ots=t_Kbo5koiR&sig=Blb_CIbCJjhkKKKIxplnPZ69RqY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwivufGK1YbOAhWIORoKHYKYCnwQ6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=bolsa%20da%20mesma%20cor%20pendurada%20num%20dos%20bra%C3%A7os%20cruzados&f=false)
>
> De súbito, **num acesso** de fúria, desferiu um soco **num dos vidros** do armário e rompeu-o em pedaços. [[Erico Veríssimo, *O Tempo e o Vento* (parte 3, tomo 2), 1961]](https://books.google.pt/books?id=hzruAAAAMAAJ&q=%22num%20acesso%20de%20f%C3%BAria,%20desferiu%20um%20s%C3%B4co%20num%20dos%20vidros%22&dq=%22num%20acesso%20de%20f%C3%BAria,%20desferiu%20um%20s%C3%B4co%20num%20dos%20vidros%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwijkKnW5IbOAhVLthoKHfM2CIIQ6AEIUDAE)
>
> Nessa noite, Rubião sonhou com Sofia e Maria Benedita. Viu-as **num grande terreiro**, apenas vestidas de saia, costas inteiramente despidas; [[Machado de Assis, *Quincas Boraba*, 1891]](https://pt.wikisource.org/wiki/Quincas_Borba/CIX)

Comment: nalgumas não existe em pt-BR, pelo menos não na oralidade comum

Comment: André Lira disse: "nalgumas não existe em pt-BR, pelo menos não na oralidade comum". Como "não existe"? Pode até ser mais comum em Portugal do que no Brasil, onde provavelmente é menos usual; mas não significa que "não exista" em pt-BR. Ocorrências em livros: https://www.google.com.br/search?q=%22nalguma%22&num=100&newwindow=1&dcr=0&source=lnms&tbm=bks&biw=1920&bih=974

Comment: O português do Brasil parece estar a evoluir num sentido de ser cada vez menos sintético.

Comment: @Rui, também noto isso nalgumas coisas. Mas enquanto coisas como *dizer para ela* em vez de *dizer-lhe* me parecem ser coloquiais, afastando-se  da norma culta patente na literatura portuguesa e brasileira do passado, *em um* em vez de *num* é sobretudo observado na escrita e preserva o que encontramos em autores do sXIX. Vê tambem [esta pergunta sobre a informalidade de *num* no Brasil](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3517/sobre-a-informalidade-de-num-numa-versus-em-um-em-uma-no-brasil)