# Sobre a informalidade de «num», «numa» versus «em um», «em uma» no Brasil

Tags: uso-de-palavras, português-brasileiro, informalidade, contrações

Dei-me conta recentemente que a contração da preposição *em* com os pronomes indefinidos — ***num, numa*** e plurais — é no Brasil por muitos considerada  apropriada apenas em registos informais e tem vindo a ser substituída na escrita por ***em um, em uma***, etc. Isto causou-me grande surpresa, pois em Portugal usa-se a forma separada só nalgumas construções (ver [esta pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3041/por-que-raz%C3%A3o-dizemos-dois-em-um-e-n%C3%A3o-dois-num)). E não me lembro de ouvir *em um, em uma*, etc. aos meus amigos brasileiros. Significa isto que se escreve *em um*, mas toda a gente diz *num*? E a minha questão principal é desde quando e com que base é que se recomenda o uso da contração apenas no registo informal.

Fui procurar na net, mas não encontrei ninguém a justificar a informalidade de *num, numa*, etc. O que encontrei foram indivíduos, incluindo o Caetano Veloso, a insurgir-se contra a recomendação. Vejam o [artigo do Caetano Veloso](http://oglobo.globo.com/cultura/sem-num-nem-numa-11340534), mais [este na *Veja*](http://veja.abril.com.br/blog/sobre-palavras/consultorio/num-ou-em-um-entrando-numa-boa-discussao/), e ainda [este no Instituto Euclides da Cunha](http://www.linguabrasil.com.br/nao-tropece-detail.php?id=97). Também os dicionários online e o Houaiss (edição portuguesa; não sei se a brasileira é diferente) nada dizem sobre a informalidade de *num*; ao contrário de *pra* ou *prá* (por *para* e *para a*) que vêm indicados como informais.

Dei também uma vista de olhos a dois autores consagrados. [Machado de Assis (1839-1908)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89rico_Ver%C3%ADssimo) no *D. Casmurro* usas as duas formas: curiosamente prefere *em um* a *num*, mas *numa* a *em uma*. [Erico Veríssimo (1905-75)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89rico_Ver%C3%ADssimo) no primeiro capítulo de [*O Tempo e o Vento*](https://vivelatinoamerica.files.wordpress.com/2014/01/o-tempo-c3a9-o-vento-erico-verissimo.pdf), emprega apenas as formas contraídas (27 ocorrências). Nas duas obras, *num* e *numa* aparecem em trechos de escrita muito cuidada.

O Erico Veríssimo e os artigos mencionados acima parecem indicar que no passado recente não havia esta preocupação de relegar o *num* e *numa* para o registo informal. Isto é mesmo assim? Ou estes autores serão enviesados ou terão tido experiências muito particulares? Se o *num* e *numa* já foi aceite em qualquer registo, quando, como, e com que base surgiu esta ideia que *num* e *numa* não são apenas informais? E há quem use *em um, em uma* na fala?

Comment: No Brasil é bastante comum o uso de _em um/em uma_ na fala.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Encontrei 4 questões dentro da sua pergunta e as respondi separadamente. Espero ter entendido corretamente.

**1.**     Isto é mesmo assim?

**2.**     Ou estes autores serão enviesados ou terão tido experiências muito particulares?

**3.**     Se o num e numa já foi aceite em qualquer registo, quando, como, e com que base surgiu esta ideia que num e numa não são apenas informais?

**4.**     E há quem use em um, em uma na fala?

---

**1.**  Sim, isto é mesmo assim! Conseguimos ver *num* livro publicado em 1856 que esses pronomes eram normalmente utilizados não só pelo consagrado *Machado de Assis*, mas também por *Casimiro de Abreu* em [*Camões e o Jau*](http://www.projetolivrolivre.com/Camoes%20e%20o%20Jau%20-%20Casimiro%20de%20Abreu%20-%20Iba%20Mendes.pdf).

> “ANTÔNIO
>
> Os Lusíadas nunca!
>
> Por quem sois, suspendei! sou que o peço:
>
> Que não se queima assim **num** só momento
>
> **Dum** poeta imortal a rica c’roa,
>
> E o mais nobre brasão **dum** povo inteiro.
>
> Oh!vou salvá-los. (Corre para Camões)”

Também se observa o uso das combinações entre a preposição *‘de’* + artigo indefinido *‘um’*, gerando o ***‘dum’***.

**2.**  Alguns autores tem em suas convicções que se deve analisar o contexto considerando-o **formal** ou **informal** antes de utilizar *‘num(a)’* ou *‘em um(a)’*.
É o caso que Reginaldo Passadori comenta [nesta matéria da revista EXAME](http://exame.abril.com.br/carreira/noticias/em-um-ou-num-qual-e-o-certo):

> “(B) Ao participar dos cursos de Comunicação Verbal, certamente estará num ambiente próprio para suas necessidades da fala.
>   Ao participar dos cursos de Comunicação Verbal, certamente estará em um ambiente próprio para suas necessidades da fala.”
>
> “Percebeu o contexto? Há um tom de informalidade e familiaridade nas mensagens, que poderia ter uma característica mais elaborada por parte do emissor, mas as combinações conferiram esta orientação.”
>
> “Agora o uso de uma forma ou de outra só depende da sua escolha para se expressar no ambiente que você se está inserido, por isso, é importante esta avaliação.”

**3.**  [Marcos Bagno acredita que essas mudanças foram engendradas principalmente por recomendações equivocadas vindas dos docentes de Português, que ele caracteriza como **preconceito linguístico**](http://e-proinfo.mec.gov.br/eproinfo/blog/preconceito/vamos-largar-as-muletas-e-andar-livremente-pela-escrita.html):

> “Algumas práticas pedagógicas empedernidas são mais resistentes que velhos hábitos e preconceitos sociais. No caso do ensino de português nas nossas escolas, fico espantadíssimo ao descobrir que muitos docentes continuam fazendo recomendações completamente equivocadas a seus alunos no que diz respeito à produção textual. Essas recomendações acabam se fossilizando no inconsciente dos estudantes e se transformando em hábitos petrificados, difíceis de abandonar.
>   Uma dessas recomendações sem fundamento é a de que não se deve escrever **num, numa, nuns, numas** e sim “em um”, “em uma”, etc., como se essas contrações, que existem na língua há mais de mil anos, representassem algum erro dos mais cabeludos. Pois não representam: basta abrir qualquer bom escritor, do século XVI até os dias de hoje, para comprovar que essas contrações são perfeitamente naturais, bonitas e elegantes. E sempre me pergunto: por que só proíbem o **num** e não as outras contrações com a preposição **em**? Por que também não se ensina a escrever coisas como “em o”, “em a”, “em esse”, “em aquele”? Por que só o pobre do **num** e sua família sofrem tamanha perseguição? Liberdade para o **num**!”

[Caetano também toca no mesmo ponto](http://oglobo.globo.com/cultura/sem-num-nem-numa-11340534#ixzz4Gl1xPsWb):

> “Me lembro (e aqui vai uma homenagem irônica, tanto aos linguistas quanto aos defensores da gramática da norma culta) de ter exposto minha estranheza em relação ao abandono do “num” e do “numa” (e, consequentemente, é claro, do “nuns” e do “numas”) no blog “obraemprogresso” e ter recebido resposta sóbria de Heloisa Chaves, a mais atenta às questões da língua entre os comentadores, confessando que de fato sempre dizia “num” mas escrevia “em um”. Aprendera na escola.”

Essa ideia pode ter surgido equivocadamente. As combinações que resultam no *‘num’* e *‘numa’* e todas as outras entre preposições **(a, de, em, por)** e artigos indefinidos **(um, uns, uma, umas)**, estão corretas como mostram várias gramáticas da Língua Portuguesa, que comumente não referenciam essa discussão entre **formais** e **informais**.

Consultei algumas gramáticas: [Moderna Gramática Portuguesa – Evanildo Bechara](http://lelivros.today/book/baixar-livro-moderna-gramatica-portuguesa-evanildo-bechara-em-epub-mobi-e-pdf/)

[Português Esquematizado – Agnaldo Martino](http://lelivros.today/book/download-portugues-esquematizado-agnaldo-martino-em-epub-mobi-e-pdf/)

[A Gramática Para Concursos Públicos – Fernando Pestana](http://lelivros.today/book/baixar-livro-a-gramatica-para-concursos-publicos-fernando-pestana-em-pdf-epub-e-mobi/)

**4.**  [Caetano observa a transcrição da fala de Alexandre Frota em sua biografia](http://oglobo.globo.com/cultura/sem-num-nem-numa-11340534#ixzz4Gl1xPsWb):

> “Mesmo na biografia de Alexandre Frota, em que o português é tratado com demasiada licença, repete-se, até nas transcrições de falas do biografado, a suposta fineza de grafar a preposição separada do artigo.
>   Imagino o Alexandre Frota contando que, “em uma noite”, botou pra “fuder”. Pode ser que, influenciados pela escrita, alguns já falem assim e eu, com o ouvido viciado, não ouça.”

Agora, observe a [transcrição da conversa entre o ex-Presidente do Senado Federal , Renan Calheiros e o ex-senador, Sérgio Machado](http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/poder/2016/05/1774719-em-conversa-gravada-renan-defende-mudar-lei-da-delacao-premiada.shtml), feita pela Folha de São Paulo:

> “**MACHADO** - Renan, só se fosse imbecil. Como é que tu vai sentar **numa** mesa para negociar e diz que está ameaçado de preso, pô? Só quem não te conhece. É um imbecil.”
>
> (...)
>
> “**RENAN** - Aí eu defendi, me perguntou, me chamou **num** canto. Eu acho que essa hipótese, eu disse a ele, tem que ser guardada, não pode falar nisso. Porque se houver um quadro, que é pior que há, de radicalização institucional, e ela resolva ficar, para guerra...”

Frota tentou ser um pouco mais elegante na fala quando optou pela separação entre a preposição e o artigo, que ficou parecendo bruscamente forçado. Já Renan e Machado não quiseram ser finos enquanto eram gravados sem perceberem, era uma conversa ***normal***. Nesse ponto que surge o **preconceito linguístico**, tratado por Marcos Bagno como *perseguição ao coitado do num*, um dos principais influenciadores na fala e na escrita de todos. Mesmo assim conclui-se que é difícil identificar quem realmente use com espontaneidade a separação entre a preposição e o artigo, ***num, nuns, numa e numas soam naturalmente na fala***.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta tão completa. Dás a ideia que essa "perseguição ao coitado do *num*" é uma espécie de culto, mas sem profeta de nomeada. Tens ideia quando é que começou? Há várias diferençazinhas no português brasileiro, especialmente no coloquial, relativamente ao europeu. Eu tou habituado a praticamente tudo: *ir na casa* (aqui é sempre *ir a/para casa*); *perguntar para* (aqui, *perguntar a*). Mas verdadeiramente tropeço no *em um*. Possivelmente porque não o ouço aos meus amigos, enquanto tudo o resto ouço.

Comment: Jacinto, não encontrei registro datado deste fato, mas conseguimos perceber que ele realmente existe! Por aqui falamos *'vou na casa do José'*, *'pergunte pra maria', mas quando se trata de algo mais formal usamos o *'ir a/ para'*, *'pergunte a'*. Também constatei a respeito do *'num'* o fato de que nos textos jornalísticos não é habitual ver essa combinação. Somente vi separado: [Inevitavelmente, o assessor mostrou no próprio celular uma foto da servidora **em um** dos protestos contra o impeachment.](http://www.cartacapital.com.br/revista/913/no-planalto-temer-realiza-expurgo-em-massa)

Answer (score 2):

Atenção: Essa é minha opinião particular não tenho formação nem li o suficiente para que este texto não passe somente de opinião pessoal.

Bem não sou nenhum especialista, mas darei minha opinião como nativo. Quando nós brasileiros vamos à escola e estudamos gramática percebemos que há uma certa discrepância entre o nosso português falado e o escrito. Essa discrepância faz o brasileiro refletir um pouco mais ao tentar falar na língua formal (que tecnicamente exigiria mais uso da gramática). Isso faz surgir alguns mitos, como por exemplo:

- É considerado mais formal usar o verbo *haver* em vez de *existir* ou *ter*;
- Uso da ênclise (ex.: salve-me) é mais formal que a próclise (ex.: me salve).

Na maior parte dos casos é considerado mais formal a forma que se usava no passado (ou a população presume que se usava) — a forma como os aristocratas provavelmente falavam português.

***Em um*** é mais formal porque presume-se que era mais usado antigamente. Talvez se não fosse tido como tão incomum usar ***de o*** e ***em a*** ao invés de ***do*** e ***na*** estes seriam muito usados na discussão formal 
(na verdade mesmo sendo muito incomum aposto que exista quem escreva *em a* e *de o*).

Comment: É uma perspetiva interessante. Vamos o ver o que o pessoal diz. Aqui em Portugal é verdade que já se usou *em um, em uma* no passado. Por exemplo, o escritor Júlio Dinis (1839-71) era assim que escrevia; também escrevia *por o/a* em vez de *pelo/pela*. Mas agora toda a gente diz e escreve *num, numa*. E isto já vem de trás: estive agora a ver *A Cidade e as Serras* do Eça de Queiroz (1845-1900), e só encontro *num* e *numa*. Resta saber é quando é que essa oposição ao *num, numa* começou. O Erico Veríssimo parece não se ter importado. O Caetano Veloso diz que é uma coisa relativamente recente.

Comment: *"É considerado mais formal usar o verbo haver em vez de exigir ou ter;"* - não seria **existir** ao invés de **exigir**?

Comment: verdade! não havia reparado, acho eu foi o correto do celular já consertei